# Android Studio ImageView Array NullPointerException

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, nullpointerexception, imageview

I'm working on a dice simulator (my second ever project for figuring everything out). I have five dice images and the variables for them in an array that I want to loop through. Android Studio give me a NullPointerException at different points of the Switch case and I can't figure out why.
Here are my variables and the array including the method:

```
private ImageView imageViewDiceOne;
private ImageView imageViewDiceTwo;
private ImageView imageViewDiceThree;
private ImageView imageViewDiceFour;
private ImageView imageViewDiceFive;
private ImageView[] imageViewDice = new ImageView[]{imageViewDiceOne, imageViewDiceTwo,
        imageViewDiceThree, imageViewDiceFour, imageViewDiceFive};
private Button mButtonThrow;
private int diceValue;

private int rollDice() {
    this.diceValue = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;

    return this.diceValue;
}

private void setImageViewDice(){
    for(int i = 0; i < imageViewDice.length; i++) {

        switch (rollDice()) {
            case 1:
                imageViewDice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.dice1);
                break;
            case 2:
                imageViewDice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.dice2);
                break;
            case 3:
                imageViewDice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.dice3);
                break;
            case 4:
                imageViewDice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.dice4);
                break;
            case 5:
                imageViewDice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.dice5);
                break;
            case 6:
                imageViewDice[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.dice6);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my OnClickListener:

```
    mButtonThrow = findViewById(R.id.button_throw);
    mButtonThrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View viewFiveDice) {
                setImageViewDice();
        }
    });
```

And here is my exception (line 45 was case 5 of the Switch but that changed in every try and line 68 is my OnClickListener):

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
    android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.dice.FiveDice.setImageViewDice(FiveDice.java:45)
    at com.example.dice.FiveDice.access$000(FiveDice.java:10)
    at com.example.dice.FiveDice$1.onClick(FiveDice.java:68)
```

Thank you for helping a newcomer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're not initializing your ImageViews, so that's your first problem.

Instead of:

```
private ImageView imageViewDiceOne;
private ImageView imageViewDiceTwo;
private ImageView imageViewDiceThree;
private ImageView imageViewDiceFour;
private ImageView imageViewDiceFive;
private ImageView[] imageViewDice = new ImageView[]{imageViewDiceOne, imageViewDiceTwo, imageViewDiceThree, imageViewDiceFour, imageViewDiceFive};
```

Assuming this is in an Activity, you would need to do something like:

```
private ImageView[] imageViewDice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    imageViewDice = new ImageView[5]; // Initialize array

    // Set each reference in the array to something valid
    imageViewDice[0] = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView1);
    imageViewDice[1] = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView2);
    imageViewDice[2] = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView3);
    imageViewDice[3] = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView4);
    imageViewDice[4] = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView5);
}
```

If this does not make sense, I'd suggest taking a break away from Android and focusing on learning Java / Kotlin and understanding how the language works first.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry for not posting my OnCreate as well. I've initialized the ImageViews there (not with the array indexes but with the variables mentioned in my initial post). I've tried your code but still receive the same error with it. From my understanding all that was different in your code is that the image views are assigned one by one instead of being written directly inside the array. Correct? Is there something else that could be the reason for this error? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post your FULL CODE that is causing the problem. I can't guess at what your issue could be.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort in solving this! I do appreciate it and will try to phrase future questions better and to post more code that might be relevant. I thought that I did post the Full Code that was causing the problem - the OnCreate was/is working fine. By now I've changed it so now the method setImageViewDice() does not contain a loop/switch anymore. As this was the only thing changed the loop through the array or the switch must've caused this to happen but I still do not know why or how that happened.